# ¿Cómo registrar datos de cierta cantidad de arreglos 1 por 1?

Tags: java, java-8

-Buenas noches, tengo un problema, el cual trata de que tengo una cierta cantidad de arreglos (en este caso son 5, pueden ser más o menos), quiero que cuando haga los ciclo for de registrar datos dentro de cada arreglo haga la primera pasada en todos los arreglos, para luego pasar a la segunda vuelta de todos los arreglos Ejm: 1-1-1-1-1, 2-2-2-2-2, y así sucesivamente.

```
    public static void operacion(String desicion){
        int tamanio=0;
    if(desicion.equalsIgnoreCase("registrar personal")){
        tamanio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados a registrar: "));
        String nombre[] = new String[tamanio];
        String apellido[] = new String[tamanio];
        String edad[] = new String[tamanio];
        String cargo[] = new String[tamanio];
        String direccion[] = new String [tamanio];
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Lo que se me ocurre es hacer que un array contenga esos arreglos, osea como una matriz y un ciclo anidado.

Comment: Estoy pensando desde ayer pero no encuentro solución bro, podrías ayudarme en tu idea? Si es así lo agradecería mucho :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastaria con un ciclo `for` usando el numero de elementos seleccionado. Adicionalmente, para informar el numero de item que se esta registrando, se puede usar [`showInputDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) el titulo del dialogo (parametro `title`) indicando en que numero de item va.

```
public static String showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                 Object message,
                 String title,
                 int messageType)
```

Quedaria de esta manera:

```
tamanio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados a registrar: "));
String nombre[] = new String[tamanio];
String apellido[] = new String[tamanio];
String edad[] = new String[tamanio];
String cargo[] = new String[tamanio];
String direccion[] = new String [tamanio];
for(int index=0; index<tamanio; index++){
    String title = "Empleado #"+(index+1); // el titulo del dialogo (Empleado #1, #2, etc)
    nombre[index] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el nombre: ",title,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    apellido[index] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el apellido: ",title,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    ....//y asi sucesivamente
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias compañero :D, voy a probarlo para ver que tal me va con tu ayuda, saludos!.